# Sql counting records

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query atm

```
select  Especialidade,Seguradora as 'Plano de Saúde',CodConsulta
from [dbo].[Seguro]
inner join [dbo].[FichaPaciente] on [dbo].[Seguro].[CodFichaPaciente]=[dbo].[FichaPaciente].[CodFichaPaciente]
inner join [dbo].[Consulta] on [dbo].[Consulta].[CodFichaPaciente]=[dbo].[FichaPaciente].CodFichaPaciente
inner join [dbo].[Medico] on [dbo].[Consulta].CodMedico = [dbo].[Medico].CodMedico 
inner join [dbo].[Especialidade] on [dbo].[Medico].CodEspecialidade=[dbo].Especialidade.CodEspecialidade
where seguradora = 'Médis'
order by especialidade
```

This is the current output :

```
Especialidade       plano saude codconsulta
Cardiologia            Médis         4
Cardiologia            Médis         6
Clinica Geral          Médis         1
```

This is how i want my output to be :

```
Especialidade       plano saude  counted records 
Cardiologia            Médis         2
Clinica Geral          Médis         1
```

Been trying this for hours cant get to the answaer if someone can give me a hand, tryed count but the output would be the total on medis and i want the total by especialidade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregate function `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this:

```
select  Especialidade,Seguradora as 'Plano de Saúde',Count(*) as CountedRecords
from [dbo].[Seguro]
inner join [dbo].[FichaPaciente] on [dbo].[Seguro].[CodFichaPaciente]=[dbo].[FichaPaciente].[CodFichaPaciente]
inner join [dbo].[Consulta] on [dbo].[Consulta].[CodFichaPaciente]=[dbo].[FichaPaciente].CodFichaPaciente
inner join [dbo].[Medico] on [dbo].[Consulta].CodMedico = [dbo].[Medico].CodMedico 
inner join [dbo].[Especialidade] on [dbo].[Medico].CodEspecialidade=[dbo].Especialidade.CodEspecialidade
where seguradora = 'Médis'
group by Especialidade,Seguradora
order by especialidade
```

Read more about `COUNT()` [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175997.aspx).

Comment: That did it perfectly , i will acept answer in minute i can thank you